# Navigate from Swift screen to React Native screen with Wix/react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using [Wix/react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/externalComponent) external component to navigate from React-Native to Swift/Kotlin pages. Is there any way to navigate from a Swift/Kotlin screen to a specific React-Native screen?

So far I've only been able to use the standard back buttons to navigate back to the original React-Native page that I navigated from and I haven't had much luck finding documentation.